# How to send OTP to mobile using Laravel and Firebase

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement phone verification in my laravel project using Firebase `signInWithPhoneNumber` function. I had some problems at first but I managed to put everything together, but now this error is thrown when trying to call `signInWithPhoneNumber`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'verify')
    at _verifyPhoneNumber (phone.ts:190:33)
    at signInWithPhoneNumber (phone.ts:190)
```

I am actually not good at js so I can't try to debug this error, I tried searching but cou'dn't find an answer. I found a similar issue on [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7516).

My code:

```
import {
        initializeApp
    } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js'

    import {
        getAuth,
        signInWithPhoneNumber,
        RecaptchaVerifier
    } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js'

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "puxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "pxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        appId: "1:434692xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx168c8757df",
        measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    const auth = getAuth()

    window.onload = function() {
        render();
    };

    function render() {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', {
            'size': 'normal',
            'callback': (response) => {
                // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
                // ...
                console.log(response)
            },
            'expired-callback': () => {
                // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
                // ...
            }
        });
        window.recaptchaVerifier.render();
    }

    $('#send-code').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        SendCode()
    })

    function SendCode() {
        var number = $("#phone").val();


        signInWithPhoneNumber(number, window.recaptchaVerifier).then(function(confirmationResult) {

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            coderesult = confirmationResult;

            console.log('success')

        });

    }
```

can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?